# Differences in Java invocation between running application from Eclipse vs. from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I observe a bug in a Java application, which only occurs when I run the application from the system command line, but not when I run the application from within Eclipse Mars. I hope that knowing about the technical differences between these ways to start the application will help me find the bug.

So my question is: Are there any special things Eclipse does when starting an application, e.g. setting additional VM arguments? And can I somehow reproduce the way Eclipse runs an application when I start it from the command line?

**Edit:**

I had encoding issues, i.e. some non-ASCII characters were displayed correctly while running the application in Eclipse but not while running from the command line. I found out that the code relied on the default system character set being UTF-8, which is obviously incorrect (I run Windows with Latin1). When running from Eclipse on the same computer, however, Java's default character set is set to UTF-8. For this reason, I could not reproduce the bug in the IDE. I finally ran the program from a shell and used remote debugging to find the bug.

Comment: Which bug do you observe ?

Comment: Can you provide a repro code ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference between running a program in Command line w.r.t. running it in an IDE.(But just remember that you can achieve all the functionality of an IDE in command line)
For Eclipse you can read the topics as available in http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-12.htm.

Comment: This shows how to start an application from the IDE. I was interested in the technical details, i.e. does Eclipse invoke the java binary in the system shell, or does it use other means to start a VM and run my program.